# Sending redirect from ActionRequest with parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to redirect to another portlet in ActionRequest and I need to send a parameter. When I add it to the response it ignores it.

```
@ActionMapping(params = { "action=create" })
public void create(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response, 
@Valid @ModelAttribute("formObject") FormObject formObject,
BindingResult result) throws IOException, RepositoryException, 
PortalException, SystemException {

    // do some stuff and then

    response.setParameter("action", "myAction");
    response.sendRedirect("/next-portlet");

}
```

`myAction` doesn't get passed to the next portlet unfortunately. How can I achieve this, please?

Comment: Add it to the redirect:

      response.sendRedirect("/next-portlet?action=myAction");

Comment: @lulu88: I was considering that as a last option, but I'll probably have to do it.. I'm running out of ideas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work. I had to use

```
response.setRenderParameter("action", "myAction");
```

Now it finally adds the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use session

```
actionRequest.getPortletSession().setAttribute("action", "myaction");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately :( Dunno why, sounds logical.